# 2 Sticks 4gb(1866) compatible with 2100(oc) supported motherboard?

Tags: memory, ddr3

Does 1866 ram stick work on 2133(oc) Supported motherboard. I'm pretty confused. Sticks are DDR3. I have MSI 970 MOBO and FX6300(AM3+) Processor.

Comment: A bit of browsing through the manual of your motherboard (which you did not specify) or through its QVL would have answered your question immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact model of your CPU and motherboard, one can only guess - but in this case, the guess is extremely confident:

**Yes, you can use it.** Generally, speeds lower than the maximum speed are supported by virtually all motherboards and CPUs. However, if you would be sure to have maximum compatibility, ask your RAM's/motherboard's manufacturer's compatibility list - or simply try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DDR3-1866 works on MBs supporting DDR3-2133 and it will work at 1866Mhz-speed.